# Sync a bucket with AWS ruby tools

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon's official `aws-sdk` gem, but I can't seem to find any funcionality that works like the command line tool `aws s3 sync <path> <bucket>`. Does it exist or am I forced to upload each file separately (slow)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have an api call that achieves that.

the sync is basically a call to get the objects, a call to inspect your local path and after that uploads/downloads to bring the 2 locations in sync. that's what the was cli tool does under the hood.

Comment: I would imagine it reuses the connection as compared to a single put? Or does it not even do that?

Comment: I am asking because the upload with the `sync` command looks much faster than what I have in Ruby.

Comment: it's possible that there is some parallelization going on. also depending on the file sizes you may want to look into multipart uploads

Comment: looked at https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/7acf83a2e305ae1d4fbc63dbb27bbd4cf027d7e2/awscli/customizations/s3/executor.py It does indeed do multithreading to move the things faster